# Proper Redirecting using React Router v4

Tags: redirect, reactjs, react-router

As I know it there are many way to transition pages in RRv4.

- Link
- Redirect
- `this.context.router`

Looking to redirect if use gets to a page improperly. I am currently using `this.context.router` this feel wrong.

Should I move my logic from `componentWillMount` to render and instead of calling `transitionTo` render the `Redirect` in favor of its composition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use the declarative components. This is evident by the documentation not showing use of `context` and this [twitter thread](https://twitter.com/ryanflorence/status/785876845749112832) which RRv4 creators(Jackson & Florence) mention that you should be able to accomplish tasks using just the components provided.